# How to get field value from Mono<Class>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have 2 methods.

```
`Mono<Order> order = orderService.getById(UUID id);`
```

AND

```
Mono<Truck> truck = vehicleService.getByTruckId(UUID truckId);
```

I get the TruckId value from the first request. Look at Order class

```
Order {

private UUID id;
private String name;
private UUID truckId;

}
```

How can I pass this `truckId` value to `vehicleService.getByTruckId(UUID truckId);` without blocking?

Comment: Now if only you could `map` something... `orderService.getById(id).map(order -> vehicleService.getByTruckId(order.getTruckId()));`...

Comment: @Alex If I am not wrong you want to chain the `Mono<Order>`  to  call `vehicleService.getByTruckId()` by extracting the trucId from  order class. Please confirm

Comment: Mono is a promise, it's not materialized yet. You can either wait for it to materialize (block) or you can register a method to get executed when the Mono is getting materialized (chaining by adding map or  doOnNext etc)

Comment: @KunalVarpe yes. I need truckId FROM Order for call vehicleService.getByTruckId

Comment: @so-random-dude 
Please show the second option using my code as an example. I will be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about the Truck

```
    Mono<Truck> truckMono = order.flatMap(o -> getByTruckId(o.truckId));
```

If you care about the aggregation of order and it's truck

```
    Mono<Order> orderMono = getById(UUID.randomUUID());
    Mono<Truck> truckMono = orderMono.flatMap(o -> getByTruckId(o.truckId));
    Mono<Result> resultMono = Mono.zip(orderMono, truckMono)
            .flatMap(m -> Mono.just(new Result(m.getT1(), m.getT2())));
```

Result Class

```
class Result {
    public Result(Order order, Truck truck) {
        this.order = order;
        this.truck = truck;
    }

    Order order;
    Truck truck;
}
```